# Adding two columns using Deedle in C#

Tags: c#, deedle

Given the following CSV file

```
A,B
2,3
5,7
9,11
```

I'd like to add the two columns, resulting in

```
A,B,C
2,3,5
5,7,12
9,11,20
```

using C# and Deedle.

```
using Deedle;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
namespace NS
{
    class AddTwoColumns
    {
        static void main(string[] args)
        {
            var root = "path/to";
            var df = Frame.ReadCsv(Path.Combine(root, "data.csv"));

            var a = df.GetColumn<int>("A");
            var b = df.GetColumn<int>("B");
            var c = df.Select(x => x.a + x.b);
            df.AddColumn("C", c);
            df.Print();
        }
    }
}
```

Neither the
[reference](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/reference/deedle-series-2.html)
nor the tutorial
([series](https://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/csharpseries.html),
[frame](https://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/csharpframe.html))
is particularly illuminating.

What is the correct `df.Select()` for this simple operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` and `b` are just `Deedle.Series` which you can perform numerical operations on. So, you can do this just by adding both series:

```
// simply add the series
var c = a + b;
df.AddColumn("C", c);
df.Print();

// output
     A B  C
0 -> 2 3  5
1 -> 5 7  12
2 -> 9 11 20
```

The [Statistics and calculations](https://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/csharpseries.html#Statistics-and-calculations) section (of the page you linked to) briefly mentions arithmetic operations. It also features a note on missing data which you might need to consider:

> Point-wise and scalar operators automatically propagate missing data.
>   When calculating `s1 + s2` and one of the series does not contain data
>   for a key `k`, then the resulting series will not contain data for `k`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is particularly addressed for C#, but I hope this F# approach can help somehow:

```
Frame.ReadCsv(@"C:\Users\flavi\Downloads\sample.txt")
|> fun frame->
    Frame.addCol "C"
        (Frame.mapRowValues (fun row ->
            row.GetAs<int>("A") + row.GetAs<int>("B")
        )frame) frame
```